# How to access filters in web.xml file set by a .properties file

Tags: ant, filter, war, websphere-6.1

I am using WAS6.1 as the server(but I guess this should not matter).I have a filters.properties file. It has key value pair (e.g. config.file.name=/usr/home/config.xml). These values are being used in web.xml as shown below:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>config.file</param-name>
  <param-value>@config.file.name@</param-value>
</context-param>
```

So I have defined a build.xml which uses filterset task from ant to define all those filters but when I try to access the home page it says that not able to find location @config.file.name@. Obviously, these filters are not being loaded properly. Here is my build.xml code which defines the filters during the compilation. What do you think I am missing?

```
<target name="compile">
    <property name="compile.target" location="${project.build.dir}/WEB-INF/classes" />

    <property name="project.build.dir.lib" location="${project.build.dir}/WEB-INF/lib" />

    <mkdir dir="${compile.target}" />
    <mkdir dir="${project.build.dir.lib}" />
    <!-- copy the web content into the build location -->
    <copy todir="${project.build.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${web.project.webcontent.dir}" excludes="**/classes/**" />
        **<filterset>
            <filtersfile file="${web.project.src.dir}/filters/${file.filter.name}" />
        </filterset>**

    </copy>

    <!-- compile the java source and put it in the classes directory -->
    <javac classpathref="classpath" srcdir="${web.project.src.dir}" destdir="${compile.target}" debug="${javac.debug}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" fork="${javac.fork}" memoryMaximumSize="${javac.memoryMaximumSize}" nowarn="${javac.nowarn}" failonerror="${javac.failonerror}">
    </javac>

    <!-- copy all the non-java resources (properties, etc) into the classes directory-->
    <copy todir="${compile.target}">
        <fileset dir="${web.project.src.dir}">
            <exclude name="**/*.java" />
            <exclude name="filters/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <!-- Create a jar file from the ${compile.target} folder  -->
    <jar jarfile="${project.build.dir.lib}/${ant.jar.file}.jar" excludes="filters/**" basedir="${compile.target}" />


</target>
```

Your feedback is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for looking at my post. It is working fine. The main issue was that the path to the properties file was not correct.